# Extract options from select list PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am looking for a way to extract the options, from a HTML select list, and place them into a comma-delimited list. Some of the lists are rather large, so I am looking for a quick way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

So for example, the list below...

```
<select>
    <option value="325">35</option>
    <option value="326">45</option>
    <option value="327">55</option>
    <option value="328">65</option>
</select>
```

...would become:

> 35,45,55,65

Comment: do you have to do it on the client side or on the server side

Comment: @COLDTOLD - Either way is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this on thew client side wit5h jquery

```
var arr = new Array();
$("#id option").each(function()
{
   arr.push($(this).text()) 
});
arr.toString();
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=arr;

<p id="demo"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4JBx/    working example

Answer (score 0):

Plain Javascript *(since you mentioned client-side is OK)*:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('option'),
    list     = [];

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  list.push(elements[i].innerText);
}

var result = list.join(',');
```